# regular expression to extract part of this HTML file

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have an html page with this script:

```
flashembed("header_container", 
{"src": "http://****.swf?__cv=3cfd4cc0ac1fad53803ff73629e93d00",
"version": [8,0],
"expressInstall": "http://****.swf?__cv=87411ea96ce42429f52b28683e7af400",
"width": 860,"height": 229,"wmode": "opaque","id": "flashHeader",
"onFail": 
function(){onFailFlashembed();}}, 
{"cdn": "http://*****/","nosid": "1","lol": "89,04","isGuestUser": "",
"navPoint": "1","eventItemEnabled": "",
"supporturl":"indexInternal.es%3Faction%3Dsupport%26back%3DinternalStart",




"***ouser***": "817",



"serverdesc": "Italia 3","server_code": "1","lang": "it","coBrandImgUrl": "",
"coBrandHref": "","customSkinURL": "","messaging": "1"});

hackEmailInviteDialog();
jQuery('#emailInviteCloseButton').click(function() 
{
.....
}
```

I need to extract the field "ouser" from this page. I tried with:

```
string pattern= @"""ouser"": "".*?,""serverdesc""";
string output = Regex.Replace(ConnectionAPI.responseFromServer, pattern, "");
```

but in output there is the whole page...

Comment: What were you expecting it to be?

Comment: You have a comma and quote reversed (right after the `?`). That's at least part of the problem.

Comment: It looks like you're just removing that pattern from the html page.
At least, that's what Regex.Replace does.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: i need to put in output string the value 817... i worked with html agility pack in past projects... but now it's more complicate (i think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated regular expression to match anything between the second pair of quotes just in case they weren't always numbers.

```
Match match = 
    Regex.Match(
        ConnectionAPI.responseFromServer, 
        "\"\\**?ouser\\**?":\\s*\"([^\"]*)\",",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
String output = String.Empty;
// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    output = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: yes it's good! I used the verbatim notation.. It works Thank you!

Comment: @RobertoPulvirenti Wonderful! Please be sure to mark the Answer you found to be correct. It helps the community.

Answer (score 2):

`"\**?ouser\**?":\s*"(\d\w+)`

Group 1 matches the `817` in that document. [Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?316rd).

Though if you're doing lots of HTML parsing on arbitrary tags, you would do better with a [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) or [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) parser. [Andrew Finnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553308/andrew-finnell) has also mentioned using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/).

As merlin2011 mentioned, `Regex.Replace` will *replace* what you're trying to pull out, not grab it for you.

Comment: Unless SAX and DOM parsers have become HTML friendly lately, they will fail miserable at parsing HTML. HTML is almost never complete XML.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell What would you recommend? I've done barely any HTML parsing and am merely parroting what I've heard.

Comment: For one a JSON parser for the specific junks of code being posted. But WebKit can probably do the job. HTML isn't required to be correct form. For example you can put <b> anywhere in HTML and it's perfectly legal to never close it.